# @AfterClass method not called when the test suit is terminated manually in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit

I notice that the **JUnit**'s `@AfterClass` method is not called when the test suit is terminated manually in **Eclipse**. This causes some trouble in debugging since I'm using the `@AfterClass` method for cleaning up.

Is there a way to make sure the clean up step is called in this case? (For some reason, I sometimes have to manually stop the tests...)

Thanks:)

Comment: Hum... It's not a good practice to have tests you have to stop _manually_. Your best chance is to fix your code/tests so that they always end naturaly. But if, for some reason, you could not... you could at least program a _shutdown hook_.

Comment: If the problem you're having is with output files not being deleted, then using unique tmp files for your output can help a lot.  If that's what you need I can post an answer with an example.  It sounds like your tests need some reworking through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: how does eclipse terminate a running program: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941751/1100135

So terminating is not specific to JUnit so JUnit can't (or maybe better: shouldn't) do anything about it. So if you reeeeaalyyyy have, you have to program it yourself. You probably don't have many options: shutdown hooks or eclipse plugins. But what if other members of your team will use IntelliJ? or plain maven/gradle/ant?

The real solution is to solve two problems in your tests design. The first is that you have to kill your tests. Fix that! What if you start using CI? The second problem is that your tests have to clean up. Why? What happens if they don't? Try to write them in a way that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I am running a big test suit and trying to find a race condition. Once the race condition shows up, I want to just stop without moving forward to the rest of the test cases (It takes a long time to finish all the test cases). The test communicates with a remote machine, and it relies on the `@AfterClass` method to collect logs from the remote machine. So it would be nice if the `@AfterClass` method is called and I don't have to log in the remote machine to read the log manually... If Eclipse won't trigger `@AfterClass`, I had better redesign the way we collect the log:) Thanks:)

Comment: try to refactor tests so they detect race condition and throw an exception. then you have 3 options: 1) use test dependency (e.g. testNG; not sure if junit plugins exist for that) so other tests won't run; 2) instead of an eclipse, use build system (maven/gradle/whatever) and configure it to stop the build after first error; 3) terminate tests as you do currently but use dedicated program for downloading logs (like logstash). after all tests should only test, not connecting to remote machine, downloading logs or bringing a brear

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this import import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass; 
instead of import org.junit.AfterClass;